# Optimization with Integral Inequality constraint and nonnegativity conditions

Tags: calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization

Trying to solve this:

$$\min TC(A,a,q)= \int_M f(A,a,q)\,dx\, dy$$
$$s.t.$$
$$a\le\int_M g_i(A,q)\,dx\,dy$$
$$q\le \text{constant}$$
$$A,a,q\ge0$$

$(x,y)$ is omitted in   $A(x,y), a(x,y), q(x,y)$   for simplicity.

I would like to find corner and interior solutions. q is separable in the objective function.

I have looked at calculus of variations but I could not find anything about nonnegativity and inequality integral constraints.